# Sink term in mass transfer

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

Assuming I have a model with initial concentration of $c_0(x)$, I would like to model a point sink for this case (considering the velocity is neglected :D)
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 c }{\partial x^2}-\delta(x)c$$
I am wondering if the last term can represent a correct sink term for this problem considering we have a well where we are producing from $x=0$ point. Second, I am not sure how to take care of sink term with Green function.

Comment: Should it really be a $+$ sign if you have a sink?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be minus. but behind the sign, the term is correct?